# How to include multiple file extensions with 'glob.sync' in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, node-glob

Can anyone please suggest how to add multiple file extensions with the `glob.sync` method.

Something like:

```
const glob = require('glob');
let files = glob.sync(path + '**/*.(html|xhtml)');
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 36):

You can use this (which most shells support as well):

```
glob.sync(path + '**/*.{html,xhtml}')
```

Or this one:

```
glob.sync(path + '**/*.@(html|xhtml)')
```

**EDIT**: I initially also suggested this pattern:

```
glob.sync(path + '**/*.+(html|xhtml)')
```

However, this will also match files that have `.htmlhtml` as extension (plus any other combination of `html` and `xhtml`, in single or multiple occurrences), which is incorrect.

Comment: What is the difference between the both?

Comment: @JaiSaravanan `@(PATTERN)` matches files that have `PATTERN` in their name _exactly once_, `+(PATTERN)` matches files that have `PATTERN` in their name _at least once_ (so my example of `*.+(html|xhtml)` also matches files that end with `.htmlhtml`, which is incorrect).